# Issue with dates in php function

Tags: php

This is my code

```
   <?php
    $time = date("Y-m-d");

    $arr = file('logs/ban_list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $to_remove = $time;
    $arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($to_remove) {
        return !preg_match("/$to_remove by /", $item);
    });
    file_put_contents('logs/ban_list.txt', join("\n", $arr));
    ?>
```

How can i tell the script to remove anything with the currentdate and anything before that date?

Greetings Glenn

EDIT : New Code

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime(); 
$lastWeek = $datetime->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$arr = file('logs/ban_list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$to_remove = $datetime;
foreach ($to_remove as $item) {
    if ($to_remove->format('U') <= $datetime->format('U')) {
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($to_remove) {
    return !preg_match("/$to_remove by /", $item);
});
file_put_contents('logs/ban_list.txt', join("\n", $arr));
    }
}
?>
```

Receiving this error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\psys\logspeter\unban.php on line 10
```

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php DateTime and DateInterval are your friends

Comment: How does you file data look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP ban logs wrong after unban](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890998/php-ban-logs-wrong-after-unban)

Comment: Its nota  duplicate its a different issue

Comment: How is `$to_remove` an Array?

Comment: Im kinda inexperienced with these type of codes thats why im trying to figure out how to make it working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your entire setup, but here is a sample of using DateTime to compare dates.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$lastWeek = $now->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));

// Select your log items and get the date value out of it
foreach ($logitem as $item) {
    if ($to_remove_by->format('U') <= $now->format('U')) {
        // Remove - expiration date is behind us.
    }
}
```

This captures the NOW time, loops over every item and looks to see if the to_remove_by date is behind us. If so, you can safely remove the item.

The `->format('U')` converts the date to a UNIX timestamp for faster comparison.

Comment: Thanks PeeHaa. I'm always mixing up my . to -> going back and forth between PHP and JS

Comment: PS I added the $lastWeek line as an example of using the DateInterval interface. I realize it is not being used.

Comment: Could you change my script and repost it im kinda bad at trying to put scripts together im sorry xD

Comment: StackOverflow isn't 'ProgramForMe.com'. You asked how to compare. We have given you the tools to excel. Tinker with it and learn!

Comment: Ive tried to adjust the code like 10 times without any results

Comment: Well, edit your question with here is my new code, here is the error I get. People can't help you re-write it without seeing all you are doing and what error you get.

Comment: will do yeah sorry im kinda new to this website

Comment: Anyone has an idea how to fix it?